# Service host tasks consuming large amount of processor

Tags: windows-10, performance, cpu-usage

On what appears to be every other boot of my computer, I find that three service host tasks consume a significant amount of CPU cycles.

[image]

If I let the computer sit, untouched, for 10-15 minutes, these three tasks remain the greatest consumers of cpu time.  If I reboot, however, they stop being cpu hogs:

[image]

What surprises me is that I can reproduce this behavior by simply rebooting my computer, at which point the three service host tasks will resume their place as top CPU users.

I am looking for suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1086107/213131) for how to separate the various services running inside a particular instance of Service Host.

Comment: update to at least [Win10 v1703, here the services are hosted in separated svchost.exe processes](https://superuser.com/a/1212692/174557). here you see which service causes the issue. Use [WPT (WPRUI/WPA) to trace](https://superuser.com/a/1203562/174557) what the service does.